Predicting financial asset returns using a vector autoregressive (VAR) model
I have trade data for 10 assets (assume stocks). The data is on 5-minute interval since 2007. A sample of the data rows and columns looks like this, where 'ivv', 'iwm', and 'xlf' are 3 of the 10 assets and the '_o', '_h', '_l', '_c', and '_v' affixes refer to each asset's Open, High, Low, Close, and Volume values for the timestamp. The entire dataset's shape is (342200, 55). The values are not prices directly by percentage changes (returns).

Theoretically, it is conceivable that every variable affects every variable. So, I run a VAR model with all variables as endogenous (and order of 5 based on AIC).  But practically, I'm most interested in predicting Close prices as you can more easily trade based on that (but Open can work too, and also predicting High and Low is still great information).
Next, I calculate R-squared for each equation as squared correlations between actual and fitted values in the equation. R-squareds range from 0.3% to 73%. All Close variables have R-squareds of less than 6% while almost all of the variables with the highest R-squareds are Open prices.
One way to visualize the performance of the predictions is to plot the cumulative actual values and fitted values. Keep in mind the values are returns so this would be cumulative returns, which is close to how the performance of a trading system would be evaluated. For asset 'ijr' Close price (R-squared=6%), this is how the plot looks:

While For asset 'xlu' Open price (R-squared=73%), this is how the plot looks:

So, I have a couple of questions:

The predictions for xlu_o look eerily good. Am I overlooking
something in my methodology?
What could explain the predictions of
all Close prices being so bad while those of the Open prices being
so good GIVEN THAT these assets do not trade over-night and today's
Close price is very much tomorrow's Open price?
Is my rationale for using all variables as endogenous and none as exogenous correct?

